# Bash/sed: No such file or directory

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script called script.sh:

```
FILE=$1
sed -i.bak "s|needle|pin|g" $FILE
```

If I run it like this:

```
bash ./script.sh /var/www/path/to/file
```

I get this response:

```
: No such file or directoryth/to/file
```

If I run `sed` by itself, passing in the same path:

```
sed -i.bak "s|needle|pin|g" "/var/www/path/to/file"
```

It works fine (even substituting the values correctly).

What am I doing wrong?

**Bonus observation**: I'm assuming it's telling me the entry path is wrong but it's hard to tell because it says ": No such file or directoryth/to/file", which indicates to me that something else is wrong. Maybe something carriage-return related?

Comment: You should quote your variables to prevent shell expansion of the value (word splitting, pathname expansion, etc.): `FILE="$1"` and `sed ... "$FILE"`. I'm guessing you haven't given us the real path...

Comment: You have non-unix line endings in your script.  Clean them up. (eg, run dos2unix)

Comment: This is caused by what is literally **the very first thing** in the "Before Asking About Problematic Code" section of [the `bash` tag info wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there must have some unprintable control character in your path string variable, you could print the content of it with `declare -p`:

```
FILE=$1
declare -p FILE
```

Comment: It's obviously a very specific control character, the CR (in CRLF, as used as a newline in DOS). CR sends the cursor back to the front of the line, which is what we see here..

Answer (score 6):

You should **use quotes** around your variables to prevent [word splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting) and [filename expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion):

```
file="$1"
sed -i.bak "s|needle|pin|g" "$file"
```

(You should also [not use all-caps variable names](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shell.xml#Variable_Names) for non-environment variables.)

---

In `bash`, each command line (after it has been split in tokens) undergoes a series of [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions), in a particular order (emphasis mine):

> - brace expansion;
> - tilde expansion, *parameter and variable expansion*, arithmetic expansion, process substitution, and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion);
> - *word splitting*; and
> - *filename expansion*.

So, when you write:

```
file='filename with spaces'
sed "pat" $file
```

the `$file` token will undergo a *variable expansion*, followed by *word splitting*, and the command will now look like:

```
sed pat filename with spaces
```

meaning, `sed` received three words for filename, instead of one.

If you use double quotes, the results of *parameter expansion*, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that occurred within the double quotes, are not subjected to *word splitting* and *filename expansion*. In our example:

```
file='filename with spaces'
sed "pat" "$file"
```

is expanded to:

```
sed "pat" "filename with spaces"
```

with spaces in filename preserved.